# DIFFERENT SCENARIO for ASP.NET Core "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10048): Only one usage of each socket address"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, sockets

My app needs to connect to an API using a non-fixed set of user credentials and client certificate.

The server is sporadically returning exception

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10048)

Code:

```
...

var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(currentUser.apiCertificate);

httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{currentUser.apiUsername}:{currentUser.apiPassword}");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, uri);

if (body != null)
{
    request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
}

var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
...
```

Upon research, it looks like the server will keep the socket connection a `HttpClient` established for a period of time after the request is completed. As I invoke the API for the next request/user, I create a new `HttpClient` but since the server keeps the connection for the previous request's `HttpClient` still open, the new client's request results in an exception.

I found that the solution for this exception is to either use a singleton `HttpClient` or setup `services.AddHttpClient` in the app startup routine, so that the same client is re-used. Unfortunately, this will not work for me, as I can only pass the current user's certificate in the `HttpClient` constructor.

Is there an alternate way to pass a client certificate so that I can use a singleton `HttpClient`?

I am hoping I can somehow add it to the request itself.

I think that manually disposing the client could only reduce the error occurrences, as concurrent requests will cause similar issues.

Thanks.

Comment: If the httpclient/handler instance *is* by necessity this granular: perhaps it needs to be disposed here too? I wonder if this is a socket exhaustion problem.  .

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that too, but I think it will only reduce the occurrences. Real concurrency will still be a problem. I could potentially keep a global singleton for the Handler and change the certificate, but I would then have to lock the client as I send the request to avoid concurrency errors. I was hoping I could add the cert in the Request object instead.